# How can I query IIS for MIME Type Mappings?

Tags: iis, iis-7, mime, mime-types

How can I programatically read IIS's MIME types?  I'd like to use them when I stream data to my clients [using WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937766/reading-a-file-from-a-unc-path-and-setting-the-correct-mime-type-in-a-http-reques).

Any tips, or API would be appreciated

Answer (score 14):

I'm making the assumption this is IIS7 only and you're using C#3.0 or later:

```cs
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
....
using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
  // If interested in global mimeMap:
  var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

  // Use if interested in just a particular site's mimeMap:
  // var config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site");

  var staticContent = config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent");
  var mimeMap = staticContent.GetCollection();

  // Print all mime types
  foreach (var mimeType in mimeMap)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", mimeType["fileExtension"],
         mimeType["mimeType"]));
  }

  // Find a mime type based on file extension
  var mt = mimeMap.Where(
        a => (string) a.Attributes["fileExtension"].Value == ".pdf"
      ).FirstOrDefault();

  if (mt != null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Mime type for .pdf is: " + mt["mimeType"]);
  }
}
```

You need to reference the `Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` in `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv`.

Your code also needs Administrator rights to be able to do this as well.

Comment: I finally got around to implementing this and it seems that I need to give IUSR access to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`.  From what I've read this can significantly reduce system security.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: @maker - see the last sentence of my answer *"Your code also needs Administrator rights to be able to do this as well."*. You are correct that permitting a site's anonymous user account to have elevated privileges is not a good idea. I work around this by sandboxing highly privileged operations in a separate process (windows service hosted remoting or WCF app) and expose only specific functionality required to do the job at hand.

Comment: @maker - if you're just reading these values then this post by Carlos Aguilar Mares may be of use: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2011/01/21/get-iis-bindings-at-runtime-without-being-an-administrator.aspx

Answer (score 7):

If using ASP.Net 4.5 or higher, you can use [`System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx) as follows:

```
void Page_Init()
{
    string[] extensions = new string[]
    {
        ".pdf",
        ".xls",
        ".xlsx",
        ".ppt",
        ".pptx",
        ".mp3",
        ".ogg",
        ".svg",
        ".pdf",
        ".png",
    };

    foreach (string extension in extensions)
    {
        string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(extension);
        Response.Write(String.Format("{0} => {1}<br />",
                extension,
                mimeType
            ));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
.pdf => application/pdf
.xls => application/vnd.ms-excel
.xlsx => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
.ppt => application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pptx => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
.mp3 => audio/mpeg
.ogg => video/ogg
.svg => image/svg+xml
.pdf => application/pdf
.png => image/png
```

Comment: dunno why this is not the accepted answer. well, does this require administrator rights..?

Comment: It does not require admin rights. When this question was originally asked the library function did not exist, so the OP selected the best answer at the time. I use the newer method all the time and it works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

Mime types registered to the system are defined in the registry under "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Mime\Database\Content Type".

Are you looking for mime types for a particular web site that is defined in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to reading the registry, or lowering security on the config directory, there is a pre-populated MIME database within the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: A word of warning HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.0.0 just uses the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. So you would need access to the registry and the file type to be registered on the server. This blog article is pretty good http://codelog.climens.net/2009/10/28/getting-mime-type-in-net-from-file-extension/