#  Is there a full list of mime-types / headers?

Tags: php, http-headers, download

I guess I want to ultimately build out a script that will force the browser in a sense to prompt for a download rather than go directly to the file and I want to do it based off of db entries so its obfuscated just that little bit more. My problem is I can only find a mime type or 2 to work with but I want a fair shares worth. From doc to pdf, to mp3 to avi.. My script is going to run based off extensions of files and then output the proper header just need to know what header to put out with what type of file. Is there a common list of file types known to stream or open within a browser by default that I can just go by?

Comment: there is an .NET framework alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937958/how-can-i-query-iis-for-mime-type-mappings ( still looking for PHP + Apache solution )

Comment: I appreciate the offer for a solution via .NET unfortunately the app I am building around is developed in PHP. But good call none the less, will have to keep this in mind when it comes to working on a .NET site with similar reqs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File extensions are not exactly the most reliable way to determine the file type. You might be interested in doing some MIME guessing. If you app is hosted in Linux, you can benefit from the [file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) command line tool with the `-i` option:

```
// Use escapeshellarg() to inject arbitrary file paths
$content_type = `file -i /path/to/file`;
```

Otherwise, PHP has a PECL extension called [Fileinfo](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php).

If you want to stick to file extensions, [media types are approved by the IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html).

**Update:** Fileinfo is a native extension since PHP/5.3.0 (thus no need to install a third-party app). Usage example:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, '/path/to/file');
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: I know I can test this shortly enough. Hopefully (I know godaddy has its share of constraints) But I am not ready to do this as of yet, would the $mime_type be the equivilant of application/blah where I would dump that into a header?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. So I put it as an answer.

**Testing MIME type support**

> Firebug can be used to check what headers Apache returns for different
>   image and movie types. To do this, simply attempt to load the desired
>   file in HTML. Open Firebug and go to "Net" -> "Headers" -> "Response
>   Headers". Content-type should appear there. If Apache does not
>   recognize the image/movie then it will likely be returned as
>   "text/plain". If Apache does recognize the resource then you should
>   see the correct MIME type, e.g. "video/webm". Note that if you see
>   "304 Not Modified" next to the request status, then the resource is
>   being pulled from cache and the HTTP headers may not reflect any
>   changes you have made to Apache's configuration. You can use "Control
>   + F5" to force Firefox to re-fetch all cached items.

From the hint above, you can test content type response from web server by parsing server response. If `text/plain` is returned, that means the MIME is not supported.