# Get file extension or "HasExtension" type bool from Uri object C#

Tags: c#, .net, uri

Quick question:

Can anyone think of a better way then RegEx or general text searching to work out whether a Uri object (not URL string) has a file extension?

- A Uri object generated from http://example.com/contact DOES NOT
- A Uri object generated from http://example.com/images/logo.png DOES

Any thoughts welcome. Apologies if I've missed something in the .NET framework / Uri class that already does this.

---

Slightly more complexity wise.

- A Uri object generated from http://example.com/contact.is.sortof.valid DOES NOT
- A Uri object generated from http://example.com/images/logo.is.sort.of.valid.png DOES

---

I've accepted craigtp's answer; however, for what I need the solution is thus.

```
var hasExtension = Path.HasExtension(requestUri.AbsolutePath);
```

To all who had a go at this. For a full and comprehensive answer, you would obviously need a mime types dictionary to do a further check. For example *http://example/this.is.sort.of.valid.but.not.a.mime.type* would return "true" has `Path.HasExtension`, however, for what I need, I would never have this type of path coming in.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to tell those last two cases apart, unless you have a list of "recognised" extensions.

Comment: I've addressed this in my edit - good point though.

Comment: "I've accepted craigtp's answer; however," hey @LiverpoolsNumber9, this should be changed by giving your own answer in a new answer below, and then mark it as the answer (this is, by the way, totally acceptable on SO, even if you immediately have your own answer). You could still give credit to the other answer that helped, but the marked answer is not, as you show, a full answer to the question, how to get this from the `Uri` type.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the [`HasExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.hasextension.aspx) method of the [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class to determine if a Uri's string has an extension.

By using the [`AbsoluteUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx) property of the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx) object, you can retrieve the complete string that represents the Uri.  Passing this string to the Path class's `HasExtension` method will correctly return a boolean indicating whether the Uri contains a file extension.

Copy and paste the following code into a simple console application to test this out.  Only `myUri3` and `myUrl4` return True, which also demonstrates that the `HasExtension` method can correctly deal with additional characters (i.e. Querystrings) after the filename (and extension).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri myURI1 = new Uri(@"http://www.somesite.com/");
            Uri myURI2 = new Uri(@"http://www.somesite.com/filenoext");
            Uri myURI3 = new Uri(@"http://www.somesite.com/filewithext.jpg");
            Uri myURI4 = new Uri(@"http://www.somesite.com/filewithext.jpg?q=randomquerystring");

            Console.WriteLine("Does myURI1 have an extension: " + Path.HasExtension(myURI1.AbsoluteUri));
            Console.WriteLine("Does myURI2 have an extension: " + Path.HasExtension(myURI2.AbsoluteUri));
            Console.WriteLine("Does myURI3 have an extension: " + Path.HasExtension(myURI3.AbsoluteUri));
            Console.WriteLine("Does myURI4 have an extension: " + Path.HasExtension(myURI4.AbsoluteUri));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based upon the question asker's edit regarding determining if the extension is a *valid* extension, I've whipped up some new code below (copy & paste into a console app):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri myUri1 = new Uri("http://www.somesite.com/folder/file.jpg?q=randomquery.string");
            string path1 = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", myUri1.Scheme, Uri.SchemeDelimiter, myUri1.Authority, myUri1.AbsolutePath);
            string extension1 = Path.GetExtension(path1);
            Console.WriteLine("Extension of myUri1: " + extension1);

            Uri myUri2 = new Uri("http://www.somesite.com/folder/?q=randomquerystring");
            string path2 = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", myUri2.Scheme, Uri.SchemeDelimiter, myUri2.Authority, myUri2.AbsolutePath);
            string extension2 = Path.GetExtension(path2);
            Console.WriteLine("Extension of myUri1: " + extension2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This new code now de-constructs all of the component parts of a Uri object (i.e. Scheme - the `http` part etc.) and specifically *removes* any querystring part of the Uri.  This gets around the potential problem as noted by [Adriano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207195/adriano) in a comment on this answer that the querystring could contain a dot character (thereby potentially messing up the `HasExtension` method).

Once the Uri is de-constructed, we can now properly determine both if the Uri string *has* an extension and also *what* that extension is.

From here, it's merely a case of matching this extension against a list of known valid extensions.  This part is something that the .NET framework will never given you as *any* file extension is potentially valid (any application can make up it's own file extension if it so desires!)

Comment: -1 AbsoluteUri does not remove Query and Fragment from the URI.

Comment: @Adriano - In the OP's original question (asking merely if a Uri _has_ an extension, not _what_ it is), it doesn't have to!

Comment: Well, an URI _can_ have query and fragment part (and the **dot can be in the query part**, not in the last segment)

Comment: @Adriano Even if they do, they still have an extension. Can you provide an example where his method fails?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti This one, for example: http://www.microsoft.com/test.jpg?someValue=1.2. It'll report ".2" as extension so http://www.microsoft.com?someValue=1.2 will be reported to have an extension too.

Comment: I see, perhaps he should use [`Uri.AbsolutePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx) instead of `Uri.AbsoluteUri`

Comment: @Adriano - My most recent change should get around any problems with dots in querystrings!

Comment: Undownvoted but take a look to [Uri.GetComponents()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getcomponents.aspx) too! ;)

Answer (score 8):

The Uri.IsFile property suggested by others does not work.

From the docs

```
The IsFile property is true when the Scheme property equals UriSchemeFile.

file://server/filename.ext"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.isfile.aspx

What you can do is get the AbsolutePath of the URI (which corresponds to /contact or /images/logo.png for example) and then use the FileInfo class to check/get the extension.

```
var uris = new List<Uri>()
{
  new Uri("http://mysite.com/contact"),
  new Uri("http://mysite.com/images/logo.png"),
  new Uri("http://mysite.com/images/logo.png?query=value"),
};

foreach (var u in uris)
{
  var fi = new FileInfo(u.AbsolutePath);
  var ext = fi.Extension;
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ext))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ext);
  }
}
```

You probably need to check against a list of supported extensions to handle the more complicated cases (contact.is.sortof.valid and contact.is.sortof.valid.png)

Tests:

```
"http://mysite.com/contact"                             //no ext
"http://mysite.com/contact?query=value"                 //no ext
"http://mysite.com/contact?query=value.value"           //no ext
"http://mysite.com/contact/"                            //no ext
"http://mysite.com/images/logo.png"                     //.png
"http://mysite.com/images/logo.png?query=value"         //.png
"http://mysite.com/images/logo.png?query=value.value"   //.png
"http://mysite.com/contact.is.sortof.valid"             //.valid
"http://mysite:123/contact.is.sortof.valid"              //.valid
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP could combine your answer with this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937958/how-can-i-query-iis-for-mime-type-mappings) to generate a list of supported extensions based on MIME type configuration.

Comment: Hi - thanks for this @wdavo - it works, but I've used 'Path.HasExtension' which effectively does the same thing.

Comment: You can also use `Path.GetExtension(request.Url.AbsolutePath)` instead of the `FileInfo` class

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the UriBuilder Class. Not only can you retrieve certain parts of the url, but you can also swap them out at will.

```
public bool HasExtension(Uri myUri)
{
    var validExtensions = new List<string>() { ".png", ".jpg" };
    var builder = UriBuilder(myUri)
    foreach (var extension in validExtensions) {
        if(builder.Path.Equals(extension, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution to make it right ;)

```
        var inputString = ("http://ask.com/pic.JPG http://aSk.com/pIc.JPG "
        + "http://ask.com/pic.jpg "
        + "http://yoursite.com/contact "
        + "http://yoursite.com/contact?query=value "
        + "http://yoursite.com/contact?query=value.value "
        + "http://yoursite.com/contact/ "
        + "http://yoursite.com/images/Logo.pnG "
        + "http://yoursite.com/images/lOgo.pNg?query=value "
        + "http://yoursite.com/images/logo.png?query=value.value "
        + "http://yoursite.com/contact.is.sortof.valid "
        + "http://mysite:123/contact.is.sortof.valid").Split(' ');

        var restultString = "";

        foreach (var is1 in inputString)
        {
            restultString += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(restultString) ? " " : "") +
                  (Path.HasExtension(is1) ? Path.ChangeExtension(is1, Path.GetExtension(is1).ToLower()) : is1);
        }
```